# useEffect hook does not update useState flag, flag always remain null when it is used

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Hi I am trying to create an authentication app. To do that I create **login** page and **DashBoardPage**.

Here is my login code. In My login page code, handleSubmit and submit works correctly, and setAuthenticated, localStorage.setItem("authenticated", true) set true correctly.

```
function Login() {

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("authenticated", false)
        setAuthenticated(false)
      }, []);

    //const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(localStorage.getItem("authenticated") || false)

    const handleSubmit = async () =>{
        try{
            let res = await api.post("/login", {"email": email, "password":password} )
            return res
        }catch(e){
            console.log("Something Went Wrong")
        }
       
    } 

    const submit = (e) =>{

        if(!email.match(validEmailRegex)){
            console.log("Not Valid Mail Address")
        }
        handleSubmit()
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data.token)
                console.log(res.data.message)
                setAuthenticated(true) // It shows that it is authenticated
                localStorage.setItem("authenticated", true)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

After I entered true values in login page, I go to "/DashBoardPage" via using inspector panel.

Here is my DashBoard code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = () => {
    
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Use Effect First Entered",localStorage.getItem("authenticated"))
        const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("authenticated");
            
        console.log("Logged in user ", loggedInUser)
    
        if (loggedInUser) {
        setAuthenticated(true);
        }
    
        else {
            setAuthenticated(false)
        }
        
        }, []);
    
    
    console.log("const Dashboard Entered",localStorage.getItem("authenticated"))
    console.log("EXIT")

    console.log("One Before Return", authenticated)

    if (!authenticated) {
        return <Redirect replace to="/TestPage" />;
    } 
    
    if(authenticated) {
        return (
                <Redirect replace to="/MyProfilePage" />
        );
    }
};

export default Dashboard;
```

My problem here is **authenticated** blocks always remain null, even though I am trying to change their value in **useEffect** before rendering. As a reason for that, I cannot goto MyProfile page and always go back to TestPage. Can someone explain why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Function in the useEffect is executed [after](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:%7E:text=What%20does%20useEffect%20do) render phase of the component. So redirect is happening before useEffect.

Add `if (authenticated === null) return null;` just before the rest of your `if`s

Additional note: `setXXX` functions from `useState` hook are not updating the `XXX` vairable immediately, in-place. The variable will be updated on next render only.